# Find questions closed by a dupehammer

Tags: support, search, closed-questions, dupehammer

Is it possible to find questions have been closed by users with golden badge (i.e. dupehammer) via special request on the [search page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search)?

Comment: I don't think so. At best you could query in SEDE the posthistory table for posthistorytypeid =10 rows. In the text field you'll find the close voters, form that you have to work out if the userid's mentioned had a gold hammer at that time. Not trivial at all.

Comment: @rene what about a query that find all questions closed with less than five votes, then take the last voter, who will be either a moderator or gold hammer? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah, but I see Patrick found a more robust solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Not using the search page, but you can using SEDE.

See for example this query made by Shog9: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/425986/close-stats-for-top-dup-hammer-users

The trick is in this part of the query on the `PostHistory` table:

```
from PostHistory hc
where hc.PostHistoryTypeId=10
and hc.Comment like '101%'
and hc.Text like '%BindingReason":{"GoldTagBadge%'
```